# Copy a file from host OS to docker image

Tags: docker

I have a docker file which contains a line like this

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN curl -Lso serf.zip https://URL/serf.zip \ 
&& unzip serf.zip -d /bin \
&& rm serf.zip
```

And that means it downloads a file and extract it within the linux image (here it is an Ubuntu-14.04).

Now, I don't want to use that URL. Instead I have the file on my local (host) machine which is a Ubuntu-12.04. The question is, how can I transfer the file from the host OS to the docker image? Then, I am able to change the Dockerfile to

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN unzip serf.zip -d /bin \
&& rm serf.zip
```

?

P.S: Currently, I have the following images

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
<none>              <none>              99ca37acd529        39 hours ago        261.2 MB
data-analytics      dataset             1db2326dc82b        2 days ago          1.742 GB
ubuntu              14.04               780bd4494e2f        4 weeks ago         187.9 MB
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FROM whatever
COPY contextfile containerfile
RUN do_thing_to containerfile
```

in your case

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
COPY serf.zip serf.zip
RUN unzip serf.zip -d /bin \
&& rm serf.zip
```

1. The file must be in the build context. Conventionally, that means it's in the directory or a subdirectory below the directory containing the Dockerfile.
2. You will either have to create a layer just container the newly copied file, or use `ADD` magic to automatically uncompress it. [Both approaches have their drawbacks.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy)

Comment: I would suggest `ADD` as it will also extract the file (hence avoiding one `RUN` and its two commands).

Comment: I did mention ADD, but Dockerfile best practices recommend against it. See the link in my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you're ok having the file under the same directory (or subdirectories) of your Dockerfile, you can use `COPY`.

`ADD` will unzip it for you at the same time, removing the need for `unzip` and `rm`.

Now if you want to share the `serf.zip` file between projects, links won't do, you need to bind mount it on the host before running `docker build`:

```
sudo mount --bind /path/to/serf.zip_folder /path/to/Dockefile_folder
```